# can't \RequirePackage{hyperref} when trying to create latex class

Tags: errors, hyperref

I am a CS student and I am trying to build a simple template for my lab reports.
Thus, I looked for a guide and found [the overleaf class tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_class).

I am following it and I try to import all the packages I need (one by one) and it compiled without any problems . When importing the hyperref package I am confronted by

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option 'pdfpagelabels' is turned off
(hyperref)                because \thepage is undefined.
```

The package works fine when just using `\usepackage` in the main `.tex` document, but is it possible to make it import in the class.

I tried moving the line before other imports and tried putting

`\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels=false}{hyperref}` after the import but nothing changed.

Here are both my `.cls` and `.tex`, respectively.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{report_card}[Report Card Template(english)]

\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\LoadClass[a4paper,titlepage,openany]{report}
```

```
\documentclass{report_card}

% \usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Random Examples}
\author{Jacques}
\date{}

\begin{document}
        \href{http://www.gnu.org.com}{Something Linky}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! This is a known problem: `hyperref` needs to be loaded as late as possible, with only a few packages after it.

Comment: load hyperref later, after you have loaded the report class. (Or better load it with `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\usepackage{hyperref}}`

Comment: Aside from the `hyperref` specific issue, I generally load packages after `\LoadClass` unless there's specific reason to load them earlier. I don't know how much this matters, but some packages work by changing class defaults and loading them after the class corresponds more closely to what you'd do in a document.

Comment: @cfr I should've done that before, I stupidly followed the overleaf tutorial. They even changed it later. All of the answers are helpful